# ¿Cómo usar una vista diferente para crear y para actualizar en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

Por defecto, OpenXava usa la misma vista para crear una nueva entidad y para actualizar una ya existente. ¿Hay alguna forma de tener una vista diferente para cada caso?

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente, tenemos que definir un vista para crear y otra para actualizar, así:

```
@View(name="Crear", members=" ... ")
@View(name="Actualizar", members=" ... ")
public class MiEntidad { ...
```

Ahora hemos de refinar la acción new para escoger la vista Crear y la accion de búsqueda para escoger la vista Actualizar. Primero, definamos nuestro propio controlador, en controladores.xml, así:

```
<controlador nombre="MiTipico">
    <hereda-de controlador="Typical"/>

    <accion nombre="new"
        clase="com.miempresa.miaplicacion.acciones.MiAccionNuevo"
        imagen="new.gif" 
        icono="library-plus"
        atajo-de-teclado="Control N"
        pierde-datos-cambiados="true">
        <poner propiedad="restoreModel" valor="true" />
    </accion>
    
    <accion nombre="search" oculta="true"
        clase="com.miempresa.miaplicacion.acciones.MiAccionBuscar"/>

</controlador>
```

Y ahora asignamos este controlador a nuestro módulo, y definimos la acción de búsqueda para el módulo. Escribimos nuestro módulo de esta manera en aplicacion.xml:

```
<modulo nombre="MiModulo">
    <var-entorno nombre="XAVA_SEARCH_ACTION" valor="MiTipico.search"/>
    <modelo nombre="MiEntidad"/>
    <controlador nombre="MiTipico"/>
</modulo>
```

Y ahora solo queda refinar la lógica de nuestras acciones. Para MiAccionBuscar podemos escribir:

```
public class MiAccionBuscar extends SearchByViewKeyAction {

    public void execute() throws Exception {
        Map clave = getView().getKeyValuesWithValue();   //1
        getView().setViewName("Actualizar");             //2
        getView().setValues(clave);                      //3
        super.execute();
    }

}
```

Los valores de la clave se han de capturar (1) para que puedan ser restaurados (3) después de la inicialización que hace el método setViewName(...).

Y para MiAccionNuevo:

```
public class MiAccionNuevo extends NewAction {

    public void execute() throws Exception {
        getView().setViewName("Crear");
        super.execute();
    }

}
```